# Cursor position in the IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, cursor-position

I just wrote my first program in python, but when I launch it on the IDLE the cursor immediately starts a line below my print() statement. Is there a way to set the cursor to start next to my print statement? Also I have noticed when I ran different programs that take user input, sometimes the cursors will appear above my print(). Is there any fixes to this?

[image]

Comment: This is not an IDLE question as the behavior comes from Python.

Answer (score 1):

When you prompt for input, you can put the prompt in the input call.

```
>>> name = input('What is your name? ')
What is your name? |
```

Answer (score 0):

`print()` in Python, by default inserts a new line. In order to modify this behaviour, you have to explicitly call print with following args

`print(string, end="")`

Source:-

1. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print